# C++ How to append a string at the end on a picture file?

Tags: c++

Hello I don't success to append "myText" at end end of the photo file.

```
ofstream photo;
photo.open("photo.jpg",ios::app);
photo << endl << "textAdded";
```

It doesn't works... It does not append "textAdded" at the end of the binary file...

Comment: how do you know it does not append it?

Comment: Why do you want to append text to an image file? What do you have in mind here?

Comment: Because the I see it with sublime text

Comment: This does not put the text in the image data, it puts the text *after* the image data and likely renders the image file unusable.

Comment: the code works. the file cant be opened with an image viewer anymore though

Comment: Ok but I want to hide this text into the image file...

Comment: I want to do it http://www.groovypost.com/howto/hide-text-inside-image-files/ in C++ , but add the hidden text into the same image

Answer (score 0):

Try adding photo.close(); on a new line after what you have written

Comment: Technically this should happen automatically when the stream is destroyed, but the close() method should be called and does write pending data to the file before closing.  Probably also worth adding error checking for file open errors.

Comment: This won't make any difference, the file closes automatically.